# Chai deep.include throws Error "Uncaught AssertionError: expected..."

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js, chai

I'm running tests with **mocha** and **chai**. `res.body.data` is an object array. 
When I check an array item directly by `to.include` it works fine, but it fails when I try to check the whole array by `to.deep.include`.
I'm stuck please help!

```
res.body.data = [{
  createdAt: 1573147796,
  id: "36d337d4-0184-11ea-acb9-0e4ed9667580",
  message: "Good",
  name: "John Doe",
  rate: 5
}]
//Running test

        expect(res.body.data).to.be.an('array');

        expect(res.body.data[0]).to.include({ //This works fine!
            message: "Good"
        });

        expect(res.body.data).to.deep.include({ //But this trows an error
           message: "Good"
         });
//Uncaught AssertionError: expected [ Array(1) ] to deep include { message: 'Good' }


        done();
```

Answer (score 1):

Deep.include check an array **strictly**, that it has member `{message: "Good"}`.
The test is fails, if target array element has another fields
The spec has wrong description.
For checking that an array has object that contains `{ message: "Good" }`

```
    expect(res.body.data.some((item) => item.message === "Good")).to.equal(true);
```

The test is passes when atleast one element of array contains `{ message: "Good" }`

Answer (score 0):

I am very late but this answer might help someone else.

So I was also struggling with the same issue a lot and I got it working by **converting the array of objects to string and then checking for inclusion of string** instead of the object.

```
expect(JSON.stringify(obj)).to.include(`"message":"Good"`);
```

Check the wokring example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sambhal/ywLdrehn/2/).